# Why is my screen tinted blue?

Tags: graphics

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on an HP laptop with a broken screen. I have it hooked up to an external monitor. It's been running fine this way for close to a year, but now the screen is tinted blue. I've checked monitors, cables, even borrowed an expansion base and used those outputs and it still does it.

Comment: What happened before the color change? Update? New software installed? etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Normally this would be caused by a hardware failure. If you have replaced the cables try a different monitor. If the different monitor works, then the problem is the monitor. If a different monitor is still blue, then it's likely the mother board.

A fast way to tell, is the color blue during boot? If so, it's hardware (specially if it's during BIOS POST).